# Using tranformer output files from pub run

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I'm trying to figure out how I can use transformers for my Dart Server application. So far I've read the articles at https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html and https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/ and have used that information to write the following transformer.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:barback/barback.dart';

class TestTransformer extends Transformer {
final BarbackSettings _settings;

TestTransformer.asPlugin(this._settings);
AssetId assetId;

Future<bool> isPrimary(AssetId id) {
  assetId = id;
  return new Future.value(id.toString().endsWith('.txt'));
}

apply(Transform transform) {
  transform.primaryInput.readAsString().then((text) {
      String output = text.toUpperCase;
      print(output);
      transform.addOutput(new Asset.fromString(assetId.addExtension('.upper'), output));
    });
  }
}
```

When I use `pub run` I see the transformer run, and the `print` line outputs as expected. What I'm missing is the *.txt.upper output file. I can't find such a file anywhere on my system. Where does this output end up, and how can I use it in my code? By use I mean being able to read the file with `File.open()` and, if the output is a Dart file, import it into another Dart file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know are transformers for console/server applications not supported. When I run `pub upgrade` I also see after `Precompiling dependencies` that some transformers are loaded but this doesn't seem to process your source files.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused, as I can tell from the `print` line that `pub run` in most certainly running my transformer and processing the files. Also, to even use `pub run` I have to use the https://github.com/dart-lang/async_await transformer. How is the async/await transformer working in this context?

Comment: Good question. I don't know. A few weeks ago I had a discussion with some members of the Dart team where it was briefly mentioned that transformers are not supported for server-side code. Could be that I misinterpreted something  though.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/async_await says "This transformer is useful for trying async/await with dart2js. The Dart VM natively supports async and await. If you are writing Dart code that runs only in the VM, you do not need this transformer." therefore only for client side code.